# How to convert square bracket object keys from URL location into nested object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

With:

```
var obj = { "object[foo][bar][ya]": 100 };
```

How can I create:

```
var obj = { object: { foo: { bar: { ya: 100 }}}};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Manual approach***

Split the given string with bracket, then iterate through the resultant tokens to make the nested object:

Given

```
var obj = { "object[foo][bar][ya]": 100 };
```

Split them so we get

```
var tokens = Object.keys(obj)[0]
    .split('[')
    .map(function(s){return s.replace(']','')});
    // tokens = [ 'object', 'foo', 'bar', 'ya' ]
```

Then make the nested object, inside out

```
var result = {};
tokens.reverse().forEach(function(key){
    if (Object.keys(result).length==0){
        result[key] = obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]; // inner-most key-value
    }
    else{
        var temp = {};
        temp[key] = result;
        result = temp;
    }
});
```

---

**Result**

> {"object":{"foo":{"bar":{"ya":100}}}}

Comment: That's not a very robust solution, but pretty clever way of doing it +1

Comment: @cyrbil Any suggestion is appreciated :) I always want to hear what people think.

Answer (score 3):

Their is no native things in javascript fr parsing nested object in querystring.

You can use http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/ which is pretty damn good at the job.

```
console.log(URI.parseQuery("?&foo=bar&&foo=bar&foo=baz&"));
```

If you don't want to import the full library, this is just the part for querystring parsing (full credit to https://github.com/medialize/URI.js):

```
var URI = {
  decodeQuery: function(string, escapeQuerySpace) {
    string += '';

    try {
      return decodeURIComponent(escapeQuerySpace ? string.replace(/\+/g, '%20') : string);
    } catch(e) {
      // we're not going to mess with weird encodings,
      // give up and return the undecoded original string
      // see https://github.com/medialize/URI.js/issues/87
      // see https://github.com/medialize/URI.js/issues/92
      return string;
    }
  },
  parseQuery: function(string, escapeQuerySpace) {
    if (!string) {
      return {};
    }

    // throw out the funky business - "?"[name"="value"&"]+
    string = string.replace(/&+/g, '&').replace(/^\?*&*|&+$/g, '');

    if (!string) {
      return {};
    }

    var items = {};
    var splits = string.split('&');
    var length = splits.length;
    var v, name, value;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      v = splits[i].split('=');
      name = URI.decodeQuery(v.shift(), escapeQuerySpace);
      // no "=" is null according to http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/url/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#collect-url-parameters
      value = v.length ? URI.decodeQuery(v.join('='), escapeQuerySpace) : null;

      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(items, name)) {
        if (typeof items[name] === 'string') {
          items[name] = [items[name]];
        }

        items[name].push(value);
      } else {
        items[name] = value;
      }
    }

    return items;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the parts and build a new object.

```js
const obj = {
    "object[foo][bar][ya]": 100,
    "object[foo][baz]": 200,
    "object[foo][bar][bar]": 50,
    "xy": 30
};

let newObj = {};

for (const i in obj) {
    let a = i.match(/([^\[\]]+)(\[[^\[\]]+[^\]])*?/g),
        p = obj[i];
        j = a.length;

    while (j--) {
        q = {};
        q[a[j]] = p;
        p = q;
    }
    // merge object
    let k = Object.keys(p)[0],
        o = newObj;

    while (k in o) {
        p = p[k];
        o = o[k];
        k = Object.keys(p)[0];
    }

    o[k] = p[k];
}

console.log(newObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an es6 version. Caution: Hasn't been tested for edge cases.

```
const keyPattern = /^(\w+)\[(\w+)\](.*)$/;

export function decodeParams(params) {
  return Object.keys(params).reduce((result, key) => {
    let match = key.match(keyPattern);

    if (match && match.length >= 3) {
      let [key, nextKey, rest = ''] = match.slice(1);

      result[key] = Object.assign(
        {},
        result[key],
        decodeParams({ [nextKey + rest]: params[key] })
      );
    } else {
      result[key] = params[key];
    }

    return result;
  }, {});
}
```